# How to access to asset file of android in a xamarin forms project from my view model class?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms solution, in this I have 3 projects, the xamarin forms project, the android project and the iOS project. I have a file in the assets folder of my andoird project and I would like to can copy this file from the asset to the personal folder, so I can edit it.

I some places I have read that I can use AssetManager, but although I have using Xamarin.Forms in my view model of the xamarin forms project, I don't have access to Xamarin.Forms.Context, that it seems to be the way to can work with assets.

So how I could copy a file from the asset folder to the personal folder in my view model?

Thanks.

Comment: use DependencyService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could using [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

1.Create an interface

```
public interface ISaveFileService
{
   void SaveFile();
}
```

2.Implement the interface on each platform (for example,for android)

in android project (may need request some permission):

```
public class SaveFileService : ISaveFileService
{
    public SaveFile()
    {
        var filPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "YOUR_DATABASENAME");

        if (!File.Exists(filPath))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fileAssetStream = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open("your file"))
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[1024];

                    int b = buffer.Length;
                    int length;

                    while ((length = await fileAssetStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, b)) > 0)
                    {
                        await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, length);
                    }

                    fileStream.Flush();
                    fileStream.Close();
                    fileAssetStream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle exceptions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3.Call it in your forms project like:

```
DependencyService.Get<ISaveFileService>().SaveFile();
```

Comment: greetings. i have the file in the assets folder on the xamarin.android project, and it just couldn't get located